# "an error occurred while mounting /home/aljobory/drive"

Tags: boot, mount

When I start Ubuntu must be press s latter twice times to start system:

> 'an error occurred while mounting /home/aljobory/drive' press S to skip or m to recover

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused for several issues:

- Bad/damaged partition. You should from a Live system check the partition for issues.
- Bad/damaged disk. Start considering buying a new disk, also do a backup of all your information.
- Bad syntax in the fstab file. You should verify all entries in fstab are valid
- Not existent drive at the moment of booting. This is common when you have NFS or removable media in your fstab file.

In summary, there are several causes that can cause the problem, each of them with the way to fix them. Investigate them.

Comment: thank you for your answer , the problem occur when i made upgrade for Ubuntu from 12 to 14 but i am new user can you explain what must i do

Comment: @aljobory you must investigate what's wrong. That's what you should do. I told you possible causes, find out if any of those is the cause of your problems.